# Can I rename a node in yaml-cpp?

Tags: yaml, yaml-cpp

Suppose that I have a YAML entry like `foo: bar`. Can I use yaml-cpp to rename the key `foo` to `buz` without having to copy all the content? In other words, I know that I can do this:

```
YAML::Node node = YAML::Load("foo:bar");
YAML::Node new_node;
new_node["buz"] = node["foo"];
```

However, this seems wasteful and I wonder if there is a built-in ability to just rename the key `foo`?

Answer (score 2):

Well you can do something like

```cpp
YAML::Node node = YAML::Load("foo: bar");
for (auto it = node.begin(); it != node.end(); ++it) {
  if (it->first.as<std::string>() == "foo") {
    it->first = "buz";
    break;
  }
}
```

For all I know, yaml-cpp stores its mapping items as list of pairs, so a lookup would execute a loop like this anyway.